# How do I make the following Rust code compile?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust

I am new to Rust programming language and I am just playing around with it. I read about Rust's borrow things and I think I understand why the compiler does not accept the following code, but I don't know how to make it right:

```rust
struct Pixel;

struct Canvas {
    pixel : Pixel,
}

impl Canvas {
    fn drawPixel(&mut self, y : usize, x : usize, pixel : &Pixel) {
        // Modify internal pixmap using given Pixel description.
    }

    fn setPixel(&mut self, y : usize, x : usize) {
        // Draw a pixel to internal pixmap using own pixel description.
        self.drawPixel(y, x, &self.pixel);
    }
}
```

This is the error reported by the compiler:

```
src/main.rs:14:35: 14:45 error: cannot borrow `self.pixel` as immutable because `*self` is also borrowed as mutable
src/main.rs:14             self.drawPixel(y, x, &self.pixel);
                                                 ^~~~~~~~~~
src/main.rs:14:13: 14:17 note: previous borrow of `*self` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `*self` until the borrow ends
src/main.rs:14             self.drawPixel(y, x, &self.pixel);
                           ^~~~
src/main.rs:14:46: 14:46 note: previous borrow ends here
src/main.rs:14             self.drawPixel(y, x, &self.pixel);
```

The idea in this example is to have a method 'drawPixel' which can draw a pixel according to the specified 'Pixel'. A second method 'setPixel' just forwards to the former method passing it a reference to the 'Pixel' instance associated with the 'Canvas' object.

Please don't ask me why I want to do it like this. It is a simplified version of my real use case. And I really would like to know what I could do to make this code compile.

Comment: Why a downvote without comment? I don't think my question was silly, so what should I have done in order to avoid it? Not asking a question on Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that the call to `drawPixel` in `setPixel` gives `drawPixel` two aliases to the `pixel` field: a mutable one through `self` (as `self.pixel`), and an immutable one through the `pixel` parameter. In Rust, a non-`mut` pointer is *really* a pointer to an **immutable** value. However, with these two aliases, `drawPixel` would be able to mutate the pixel value that the `pixel` parameter refers to, and its value would change unexpectedly.

If `Pixel` is a small type (say, an RGBA quad) and doesn't implement `Drop`, you can make it `Copy`, and then just pass the `Pixel` by value (see [A.B.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31492378/234590)).

If that's not possible, then consider what `drawPixel` actually needs to mutate. Does it need to mutate the `pixel` field? If yes, you need to copy the pixel somehow, otherwise the value of the `pixel` parameter will change when you mutate the field, as I explained above. In that case, you might be able to implement only `Clone` and use the `clone()` method to get a copy of the pixel.

If you don't need to mutate the `pixel` field in `drawPixel`, then you can move the fields that you mutate in a separate struct, and move the `drawPixel` method to that struct instead. This way, the `&mut self` will apply to the inner struct, which will be sure to not alias with the `pixel` field.

```
struct Pixel;

struct Canvas2;

struct Canvas {
    canvas2 : Canvas2,
    pixel : Pixel,
}

impl Canvas2 {
    fn drawPixel(&mut self, y : usize, x : usize, pixel : &Pixel) {
        // Modify internal pixmap using given Pixel description.
    }
}

impl Canvas {
    fn setPixel(&mut self, y : usize, x : usize) {
        // Draw a pixel to internal pixmap using own pixel description.
        self.canvas2.drawPixel(y, x, &self.pixel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Francis, for your perfect explanation and also for the solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

How to make it right depends on what you need and how Pixel actually looks like in real code.

As Pixel is probably a lightweight object that can be trivially copied, you can pass it by-value.

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Pixel;

struct Canvas {
    pixel : Pixel,
}

impl Canvas {
    fn drawPixel(&mut self, y : usize, x : usize, pixel : Pixel) {
        // Modify internal pixmap using given Pixel description.
    }

    fn setPixel(&mut self, y : usize, x : usize) {
        // Draw a pixel to internal pixmap using own pixel description.
        self.drawPixel(y, x, self.pixel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I also thought about this approach. But what if copying was not possible? I really would like to see a solution using references (or avoiding copies), if there is any.